# CAGradientLayer animation not in sync (animation delay)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, cagradientlayer

I was doing the weather app, everything was fine until I add the `CAGradientLayer` transition to `UIView`. It still worked but the transition took so long, around 10-15 seconds. I'm using the Apixu API for the weather. One thing to notice is the audio was perfectly playing, right away. I have checked the duration and there was nothing wrong with animation:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var cityLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var conditionLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var degreeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var gradientView: UIView!
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let gradientLayer2 = CAGradientLayer()
    let gradientLayer3 = CAGradientLayer()

    var degree: Int!
    var condition: String!
    var imgURL: String!
    var city: String!

    var exists: Bool = true

    var audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayer3 = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayerSunny = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayerSnow = AVAudioPlayer()
    var audioPlayerThunder = AVAudioPlayer()
    // Audio part.


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        gradientLayer.frame = gradientView.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        gradientView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        //gradient color view


        gradientLayer2.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.purple.cgColor]
        //gradient color view 2
        gradientLayer3.colors = [UIColor.orange.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
        //gradient color view 3

        searchBar.delegate = self

        // Audio Code starts.
        do {
            audioPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ambiance", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer1.prepareToPlay()

            audioPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "guitar", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()

            audioPlayer3 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "rain", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayer3.prepareToPlay()

            audioPlayerSunny = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sunny", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayerSunny.prepareToPlay()

            audioPlayerSnow = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "snow", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayerSnow.prepareToPlay()

            audioPlayerThunder = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "thunder", ofType: "mp3")!))
            audioPlayerThunder.prepareToPlay()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }  // Audio Code ends.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }



    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()


        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=494942fa74444eabb6973325170510&q=\(searchBar.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))")!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

                    if let current = json["current"] as? [String : AnyObject] {

                        if let temp = current["temp_c"] as? Float {
                            self.degree = Int(temp.rounded())
                        }
                        if let condition = current["condition"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            self.condition = condition["text"] as! String
                            let icon = condition["icon"] as! String
                            self.imgURL = "http:\(icon)"
                        }
                    }
                    if let location = json["location"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        self.city = location["name"] as! String
                    }

                    if let _ = json["error"] {
                        self.exists = false
                    }

                    if  self.condition == "Sunny" || self.condition == "Clear" {
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.currentTime = 0
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.play()
                        self.audioPlayer1.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer3.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer2.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.stop()
                        // Audio Code.
                        let colorChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
                        colorChangeAnimation.duration = 1.0
                        colorChangeAnimation.toValue = self.gradientLayer3.colors
                        colorChangeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
                        colorChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
                        self.gradientLayer.add(colorChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
                        //effects

                    } else if self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"cloudy") != nil || self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"overcast") != nil {
                        self.audioPlayer1.currentTime = 0
                        self.audioPlayer1.play()
                        self.audioPlayer2.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer3.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.stop()
                        // Audio Code.
                        let colorChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
                        colorChangeAnimation.duration = 1.0
                        colorChangeAnimation.toValue = self.gradientLayer2.colors
                        colorChangeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
                        colorChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
                        self.gradientLayer.add(colorChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
                        //effects

                    } else if self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"snow") != nil || self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"snowy") != nil || self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"sleet") != nil
                    {
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.currentTime = 0
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.play()
                        self.audioPlayer2.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer3.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer1.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.stop()
                        // Audio Code.

                    } else if self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"rain") != nil || self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"rainy") != nil || self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"drizzle") != nil
                    {
                        self.audioPlayer3.currentTime = 0
                        self.audioPlayer3.play()
                        self.audioPlayer2.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer1.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.stop()
                        // Audio Code.

                    } else if self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"thunder") != nil || self.condition.lowercased().range(of:"thundery") != nil {
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.currentTime = 0
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.play()
                        self.audioPlayer2.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer3.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer1.stop()
                        // Audio Code.

                    } else {
                        self.audioPlayer2.currentTime = 0
                        self.audioPlayer2.play()
                        self.audioPlayer1.stop()
                        self.audioPlayer3.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSnow.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerSunny.stop()
                        self.audioPlayerThunder.stop()
                        // Audio Code.


                    }


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if self.exists{
                            self.degreeLbl.isHidden = false
                            self.conditionLbl.isHidden = false
                            self.imgView.isHidden = false
                            self.degreeLbl.text = "\(self.degree.description)°"
                            self.cityLbl.text = self.city
                            self.conditionLbl.text = self.condition

                            self.imgView.downloadImage(from: self.imgURL!)
                        }
                        else {
                            self.degreeLbl.isHidden = true
                            self.conditionLbl.isHidden = true
                            self.imgView.isHidden = true
                            self.cityLbl.text = "No matching city found"
                            self.exists = true
                        }
                    }


                } catch let jsonError {
                    print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}



extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from url: String) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```